# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdu found in modules classes.jar com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This question may have been asked with some other context and dependencies. 
But I am still not able to figure out this even spending a whole day.

So below I'm pasting the complete Error log along with my Project level Gradle file and App level Gradle file.

Error log while trying to run the app:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdx found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdy found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzec found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzed found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzee found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzef found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeg found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeh found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzei found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzej found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzek found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzel found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzem found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzen found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeo found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzep found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeq found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzer found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzes found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzet found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzev found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzew found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzex found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzey found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzez found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfa found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfb found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfc found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgb found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgc found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzge found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgf found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgg found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgh found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgi found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgj found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgk found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgl found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgm found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgn found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgo found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgp found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgq found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgr found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgs found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgt found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgx found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgy found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgz found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzha found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhb found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhc found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhe found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhf found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhg found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhh found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhi found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhj found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhk found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhl found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhm found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhn found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzho found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhp found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhq found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhr found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhs found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzht found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhx found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhy found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhz found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzia found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzib found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzic found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzid found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzie found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzif found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzig found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)
```

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

My Project Gradle File:

```
`// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://maven.google.com' }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven{
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
`
```

App level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //resConfigs "en"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'API_KEY',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug {
            //minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/res/assets/'] } }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter:3.2.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-commons:3.2.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:3.2.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions-expandable:3.2.4@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms' , module: 'play-services-measurement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.stephentuso:welcome:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
```

Comment: you need to exlude this class from one of the gradle library

Comment: Try with `17.2.0` version of Firebase

Comment: @VivekMishra: Tried but still the same issue

Comment: @user3040153, I already added `exclude` for this package but it's not working. Any other thought?

Comment: Please once check library folder as well

Comment: @user3040153 The project does not have any lib folder

Comment: @VivekMishra. The solution states removing some FIrebase UI packages. But I exactly don't know which Firebase packages need to be removed and how?

Comment: Currently I made it working by downgrading the Google Play Services version in Project Gradle file to the following:         `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1` along with Firebase UI Auth to the version 5.0.0. `    `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0'`

Comment: that you have to do with hit and try

Answer (score 5):

In ReactNative I have the next error:

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbp found in moduules play-services-measurement-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-seervices-measurement:17.4.1) and play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)

It solved changing the next line on the `build.gradle` of android app level:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

This was my problem also..i looked for the last dependency added, and that was

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
```

What I only did, is to reduce to number lower than that, because need for it. And it worked.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0'
```

Regards Nenad

Answer (score 3):

Just add this `api` in your `dependencies` in `gradle`
**This will solve your problem**

```
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Wow. I am wondering how it's possible. can please explain this? BTW thank you so much

Comment: This 100% working. i didn't replace api but changed version to 21.1.1 and error resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was deleting the dependency "'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'" Since I am using Flutter, it seems that the Flutter framework already addss this. So at runtime the project finds 2 dependencies. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Using react-native-text-detector caused this for me. Removing this essentially fixed this error. Its a bit extreme but its better than wasting hours of valuable time on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I definitely understand the thinking behind your answer--I've certainly felt many times just to tell someone to use a different technology--but it isn't really an answer to the specific question OP asked. Typically we try to be as specific as possible with both questions and answers, emphasizing answers with actionable code examples. There is more info on providing great answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, clearly you misunderstood. I did not tell him to use a different technology I am simply offering MY EXPERIENCE. There are other packages that can be used if one experiments. I got the same error that the original poster had and I think that sharing why it happened for me will certainly help other people who come across this post with experiences similar to mine. Please read and understand before you comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved downgrading

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0'
```

Comment: I think upgrading play-services-ads from 20.6.0 to 21.0.0 caused this issue for me. Do you know what other library caused the conflict for you? I think it might be an older firebase version for me but hard to verify. Trying to figure out if I can upgrade another lib instead of downgrading play-services-ads.

Comment: I just found that this solved my issue, I didn't investigate further

Comment: The conflict for me was between play-services-ads 21.0.0 and firebase-analytics 19.0.0, I resolved by upgrading firebase to 21.1.1 (in my case, did a unity firebase upgrade from firebase version 8.2.0 to 9.6.0)

Comment: Thank toy @PatrickFay. That solved my issue as well. Downgrading google-ads was not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I updated in `app/build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.1.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.1.2'
```

this worked for me