# getting build error after updating ads dependencies to latest version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this build error while I am trying to run my application from `Android Studio.`

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbs found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzl found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfh found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgl found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgm found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgn found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgo found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgp found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgq found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhs found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhx found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.1)
```

This only happens after I update ads dependencies to the latest version.

### From :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0'
```

### To :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
```

If I change it back to `20.0.0` then it's working fine. I think the problem is with the latest version `20.4.0`.

Can anybody help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What other Google Play or Firebase libraries do you have installed? This is likely due to having another Google owned library that needs upgrading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [release notes](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes?hl=en#20.4.0) are not giving a hint.

I ended up using 20.3.0 for now which does not produce this error.

Answer (score 3):

Another Google owned library has a conflicting version of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base` installed. In my case it was [Firebase Analytics](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-analytics).

**Firebase Analytics**

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.0
```

**Play Services Ads**

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:20.6.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3
```

After upgrading Firebase Analytics from version `18.0.0` to `20.1.2` it solved the issue.

To determine which library is conflicting in your project, [output your dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235229/11809808) and find which library also installs `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base`. Then upgrade that library to the latest version.

**See also**

- [Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdu found in modules classes.jar com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70321837/11809808)
- [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50577437/11809808)
- [Fix dependency resolution errors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors)
- [View module dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree)